# How to Extract Text from Specific Spans Using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following code snippet.

```
    <div id="job-location-name" itemprop="address" itemscope=""
        itemtype="https://schema.org/PostalAddress" data-reactid="49">
        <span itemprop="addressLocality" data-reactid="50">Cupertino</span>
        <span data-reactid="51">, </span>
        <span class="break--on--small" data-reactid="52"></span>
        <span itemprop="addressRegion" data-reactid="53">California</span>
        <span data-reactid="54">, </span>
        <span class="break--on--small" data-reactid="55"></span>
        <span itemprop="addressCountry" data-reactid="56">United States</span
    </div>
```

I'm trying to extract the city and state:

('Cupertino', 'California')

But I'm only getting a text from the first span:

('Cupertino')

How can I select specific spans to get the state text as well? Here's my code:

```
    job_soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
    locations = job_soup.find('div', {'id': 'job-location-name'}).find_all('span')
    for location in locations:
        location = location.text
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [attribute selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) as follows:

```
# City
city = soup.find("span", {"itemprop" : "addressLocality"})

# State
region = soup.find("span", {"itemprop" : "addressRegion"})

# Country
country = soup.find("span", {"itemprop" : "addressCountry"})
```

Edited to improve answer based on comments. Thanks!

Comment: should be `"addressLocality"`, not `"addressLocalCity"`; also, since there's only one of each span, I think `find` would be better than `findAll`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting output using css selectors like as follows:

Code:

```
doc ='''
 <div id="job-location-name" itemprop="address" itemscope=""
        itemtype="https://schema.org/PostalAddress" data-reactid="49">
        <span itemprop="addressLocality" data-reactid="50">Cupertino</span>
        <span data-reactid="51">, </span>
        <span class="break--on--small" data-reactid="52"></span>
        <span itemprop="addressRegion" data-reactid="53">California</span>
        <span data-reactid="54">, </span>
        <span class="break--on--small" data-reactid="55"></span>
        <span itemprop="addressCountry" data-reactid="56">United States</span
    </div>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
job_soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, "lxml")
p = job_soup.select_one('div#job-location-name')
t = p.select('span:nth-child(1)') + p.select('span:nth-child(4)')
for location in t:
   print(location.text)
```

Output:

```
Cupertino
California
```